# permalink for multiple category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

hi i had 15 pages for 2 categories.. example category A and category B.... while doing so i have displayed title and content... but permalink is creating for category A not for category B... how can i code for to get a permalink for second category...

```
$cat = get_the_category();
$id= $cat[0]->term_id;
$id1= $cat[1]->term_id;

$args = array('posts_per_page'  => 15,
'cat'=> $id1,
'orderby'=> 'post_date',
'order'=> 'ASC',
'paged' => $paged,
'post_type'=> 'post',
'post_status'     => 'publish' ); 

 query_posts( $args );
 if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 $i++;
 ?>
 <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>
 <?php
 endwhile; 
 wp_reset_query(); 
 ?>
```

but the permalink is creating for $id...

Comment: Dude, use two [Foreach](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using template or page to display this two categories post. You have to run two loop for every category. If you are trying to use shortcode or something. it will be different.

```
$cat = get_the_category();
$cat_01= $cat[0]->term_id;
$cat_02= $cat[1]->term_id;

$args_for_cat_01 = array('posts_per_page'  => 15,
'cat'=> $cat_01,
'orderby'=> 'post_date',
'order'=> 'ASC',
'paged' => $paged, //I don't know what is this $paged??
'post_type'=> 'post',
'post_status'     => 'publish');

$post_from_cat_01 = get_posts( $args_for_cat_01 );
foreach ( $post_from_cat_01 as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
          //Do whatever you want here. Use divs or anything.
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>

</ul>
```

As above like this. Create another `args` for your second loop.

```
$args_for_cat_02 = array('posts_per_page'  => 15,... change the cat => cat_02 ..ect
```

Then use the loop as above.

```
$post_from_cat_02 = get_posts( $args_for_cat_02 );
foreach ( $post_from_cat_02 as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
```

Remember to change the `variables`. I just use for more explanation.

If you need my help. Please find me any of social network by searching `yeshansachithak`.