# wordpress permalink for different categories same page

Tags: wordpress

i had a list of same 10 posts for 2 different categories.... i need a separate permalinks for category 1 and category 2... how to do it...

```
<?php 
query_posts('cat=18');
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$i++;
?>
<?php echo get_permalink(); ?><?php the_title();?> // comes with li and a
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

i have 2 categories 17 and 18 via same posts.... for the first time permalinks is for category 18... after reloads it goes for permalink for category 17... i have checked with get_the_category() it shows in 2 array array[0] category 17 and array[1] category 18... so it creates permalink for first array... but i need for second one...

Comment: Hi! You have to use [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories). Then you can get post by there own categories. Using [https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). So, you have to learn about loops. [https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Try these. This is a answer actually. After this still you have doubt. We can clear those. Happy coding. Bye

Comment: <?php query_posts('cat=18');
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$i++;?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>
<?php
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>

Comment: i have done like above... for category 17 and 18 same post... for the first time permalinks are creating for category 18... after reloads it goes again to category 17 permalink

Comment: No boss, Use this [LOOP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). It's simple. If you did some coding. Please edit your question and drop some codes.

Comment: I think you ask same question in there also. [STACK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309258/permalink-for-multiple-category). Just check that codes. Or I will drop the answer here. ""*_*""

Comment: Yeshan drop the code here

Answer (score 0):

Okay! here you go. First, If you no the what is the categories that you want to get posts. Just use FOREACH LOOP. If you need to get post from 2 different categories. You have to use two loops. If is 3 and use 3 loops. Just like. If you are trying to get the link for the category. I will do below codes for you.

```
<?php 
$cat = get_the_category();
$cat_01_id= $cat[0]->term_id;//It will get the category id
$cat_02_id= $cat[1]->term_id;//It will get the category id

//Get category link before the loop
// Get the URL of this category
$category_link_01 = get_category_link($cat_01_id);//Cate link 01
$category_link_02 = get_category_link($cat_02_id);//Cate link 02
?>
Then the loops. Now I'm going to display The Category Link before the category post. Like header.

//Begin to display you post from the category. this is the loop for only one category. Please remember to change `$category_link_01` and `$cat_01_id` this for the 2nd loop
<div id="cat_title">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link_01 ); ?>" title="Category Name">Category Name</a>
</div>
//Then Loops
<div>
<?php
$args_01 = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => $cat_01_id );

$cat_post_01 = get_posts( $args_01 );
foreach ( $cat_post_01 as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div id="post_title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
        <div id="post_contents">
               <?php the_contents(); //Or you can use excerpt ?>
        </div>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```

as like above code. Make another loop using `variable`. Just read my that answer from you [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309258/permalink-for-multiple-category).

If you need my help. Please find me any of social network by searching `yeshansachithak`.